# How to copy what the printed version of a string would look like to a new string

Tags: python

Say that this is the `repr` version of my string

```
raw = ''If the third-party evaluating agency is a NACES member\xa0and uses the CDGDC for their verification, you will not need to send a report from the CDGDC and the evaluation is sufficient for your application. If not, please contact grad.info@uc.edu to find out whether your evaluation will be accepted.'' vs. ''If the third-party evaluating agency is a NACES member and uses the CDGDC for their verification, you will not need to send a report from the CDGDC and the evaluation is sufficient for your application. If not, please contact grad.info@uc.edu to find out whether your evaluation will be accepted.''
```

And this is what it looked printed

```
'If the third-party evaluating agency is a NACES member and uses the CDGDC for their verification, you will not need to send a report from the CDGDC and the evaluation is sufficient for your application. If not, please contact grad.info@uc.edu to find out whether your evaluation will be accepted.' vs. 'If the third-party evaluating agency is a NACES member and uses the CDGDC for their verification, you will not need to send a report from the CDGDC and the evaluation is sufficient for your application. If not, please contact grad.info@uc.edu to find out whether your evaluation will be accepted.'
```

What is the most efficient way of getting the 2nd version?

Comment: What do you mean getting the second version?

Comment: not sure if I'm understanding this correctly... but define raw = "<your string>", then print(raw.replace("''","'")) give your exact desired output

Comment: The "second version" *is* the string, while the "`repr` version" is a technical representation of the same string. In the interactive interpreter you usually see the repr. Don't get confused by that.

Comment: @DerekEden would that handle things like \xa0 \n and and \t?